# WPF set Grid column width to max width even if collapsed on SharedSizeGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, sharedsizegroup

I have a simple `Grid` with 2 columns and 5 rows. Only 2 of these rows are visible at once. Depending on the selection of a `ComboBox` in the first row the visibility of the other rows are changed and different `UserControl`s are shown. In the first column is a `Label` that should describe what to to with the `UserControl` in the second column (i.e. 'Name', 'Password' and so on). When the `Grid` is first shown, the second row is `Visible` and the others are `Collapsed`. 'Name' just has four letters and for example 'Password' has 8, so the `Column.Width` changes. So the GUI looks unsteady. What I want is that the `Column.Width` binds to the maximum (even if momentarily `Collapsed`) sized `Column`. We are using language files for different languages here, so I cannot set the size of the first `Column` to a fixed amount.

This is my code so far:

```
<Window ...
    ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
...
<StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static base:AppStrings.SecurityMethods}" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SecurityModes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSecurityMode}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Visibility="{Binding SelectedSecurityMode, Converter={StaticResource EqualToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Password}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static base:AppStrings.Password}" />
        <wpfControls:TextBoxEx Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Password}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Visibility="{Binding SelectedSecurityMode, Converter={StaticResource EqualToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Sms}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static base:AppStrings.MobileNumber}" />
        <wpfControls:PhoneNumberControl Grid.Column="1" PhoneNumber="{Binding MobileNumber}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Visibility="{Binding SelectedSecurityMode, Converter={StaticResource EqualToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Email}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource LabelDefaultStyle}" Content="{x:Static base:AppStrings.EmailAddress}" />
        <wpfControls:TextBoxEx Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Visibility="{Binding SelectedSecurityMode, Converter={StaticResource EqualToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=None}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource LabelDefaultStyle}" Content="{x:Static base:AppStrings.Password}" IsEnabled="False" />
        <wpfControls:TextBoxEx Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

That should be cutted to the essential problem. It later looks like this:
[image: First call]
[image: Changed to other method]
[image: Back to first selection]

As you can see the first column resized AFTER changing the `Visibility`. What I want is, that the column takes the space of the maximum sized label without setting all visibilities to `Collapsed` at a later time. That would also make the GUI look unsteady.

Comment: try Visibility Hidden instead of Collapsed

Comment: @ASh I tried that, but then the rows would all take the place and only the content would be hidden. So it would always be 5 rows in height, even if only 2 are showing.